# Display and remove longest n durations by top_n

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have data like below `myDate` from a csv file:

```
start                  end
2017-07-22 04:00:00    2017-08-05 04:00:00
2014-05-16 17:00:00    2014-05-25 18:40:00  
2018-12-13 22:00:00    2018-12-18 07:59:59
```

I also create another column for duration in days:

```
library(tidyverse)
myDate$duration <- as.numeric(difftime(parse_datetime(myDate$end, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                       parse_datetime(myDate$start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                                       units = "days"))
```

I have 2 questions:

1. I want to display top n duration (says n = 5), I do this `top_n(5, myDate$duration)` but I got this error:

> Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
>             no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')

How do I fix this?

2. How do I remove the top longest 10% of `myDate` in terms of `duration`?

Comment: You should provide reproducible data and indicate what packages you use. It'll be more friendly to other readers.

Comment: `parse_datetime()` belongs to `readr` (but I was thinking the same thing)

Comment: @DarrenTsai, I am using this `library(tidyverse)`. I have edited the question

Comment: @hydradon: for the `top_n` functions: `top_n(myDate, 5, duration)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Question 1

```
myDate %>%
  top_n(5, duration)
```

#### Question 2

Removing the top longest 10% of the duration represents retaining the top shortest 90% of it. The negative duration `-duration` means using increasing order, i.e. selecting the top n smallest values.

```
myDate %>%
  top_frac(1 - 0.1, -duration)
```

Comment: Ah, right. I hadn't realized that `top_n()` wasn't used properly. I'll delete my answer as, clearly, this is the right answer.